# Web push subscription from subdomain

Tags: service-worker, web-push

We use SaaS software without access to root directory (and without any web push service built-in). As we'd like to allow subscriptions for web push notifications.

Every web push manager service I know (like PushPushGo or Gravitec or others) requires to put JS service worker in root directory.

So I thought of calling it from subdomain delegated to other server where we have root directory access. The question is -- is there a proper way to call subscription on main domain website?
So the web push registering script / service worker is on webpush.domain.com yet the website operates on domain.com (or [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)). We are still allowed to customize JavaScript on SaaS software yet the scripts are in dedicated subfolder.

Comment: You can serve the Service Worker from a different directory and set the proper [headers for the Service Worker Scope](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2022/10/how-to-change-the-scope-of-a-service-worker/). This solution can work for Wix and other services that have special limitations. However with this method you can use a different directory (instead of the root path), but I don't think that you can use a different domain.

Comment: @collimarco thank you for quick answer! Unfortunately there also limitations on the side of Wep Push managing services. We cannot really edit the script and scope paths :(
My thought was to use subdomain and call web push registration from there.

Comment: 1. Can you find a way to serve the service-worker.js file from a subdirectory on the main domain? 2. Can you set some custom HTTP headers when you serve that file? If the answer is Yes to both questions that you can definitely install web push

Comment: Unfortunately none of these. The only thing I can do on main domain is to write custom JS from the admin panel or upload the file on server to the dedicated directory.